# Failed to execute request error for SnowSql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to log into Snowflake via SnowSql. I am using the trial account. I am executing this from the command window on Windows 10:

snowsql -a https://xxxxxx.east-us-2.azure -u randyminder

I get prompted for a password and after about 30 seconds I get this error:

*250003 (n/a): Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //xxxxxx.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=f4e6ea23-21fe-4bba-814d-51b69a801a4a (Caused by NewConnectionError('<snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CA29B68EF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))*

Oddly enough, up until about 2 weeks ago this was working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the `https://` at the beginning of your account name. Change it to:

```
snowsql -a xxxxxx.east-us-2.azure -u randyminder
```